# Inner join 2 tables into another one

Tags: sql

```
SELECT film.title, actor.last_name
FROM actor, film
INNER JOIN film_actor ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
    AND actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
```

This is the code I currenly have, I am using the sakila test database, basically I wish to show the film title and the actors last name but it doesnt work. The film_actor table contains the ids of which actor performed in what film so I want to combine both ids into that and show it. The book I'm reading doesn't explain how to combine 2 tables into one just one into another. I know the column with the films will repeat with each actor but that doesn't matter right now, I wish to solve this problem first

Comment: Your first part looks good, but your last part `ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id AND actor_id = film_actor.actor_id` is a bit off. You need to join based on the film ID in both tables. I assume you have something like `film_actor.film_id` denoting the film that the actor is in? If actors can be in more than one film, it **sounds** like you may actually have a many-to-many relationship, in which case you'd need a bridging table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two separate ON clauses for each join:

```
SELECT film.title, actor.last_name
FROM actor
INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
INNER JOIN film ON film.film_id = film_actor.film_id
```

Or an alternate syntax not using JOINs:

```
SELECT film.title, actor.last_name
FROM actor, film, film_actor
WHERE film.film_id = film_actor.film_id AND actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
```

Comment: If I try the code you provided I just get an error saying unknown column 'film_actor.film_id' in 'on clause', no idea why since that column is there and in that table.

Comment: Update: the one without INNER JOIN works fine, I just ordered it by film.title and it works great. But I still wish to know why the inner join doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The JOINs have to be around the other way as film_actor needs to be joined first. I have updated the answer.